# How to sort JSON Array at second level using PHP

Tags: php, json, sorting

I like to sort following JSON data by it's value **salary** using PHP in ascending order.

```
{
    "allresults": [
        {
            "results": [
                {
                    "Name": "Peter",
                    "salary": 1000
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "results": [
                {
                    "Name": "Riya",
                    "salary": 999
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Required Result:

1. Riya : 999
2. Peter : 1000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a custom sort function using [uasort](http://php.net/uasort). Something like this should work for you:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);

uasort($data['allresults'], function($a, $b) {
    $aSalary = $a['results'][0]['salary'];
    $bSalary = $b['results'][0]['salary'];

    return $aSalary - $bSalary;
});

foreach($data['allresults'] as $item) {
    printf("%s: %d<br />", $item['results'][0]['Name'], $item['results'][0]['salary']);
}
```

Comment: +1 In `uasort` you could even remove those 2 extra variables

Comment: The function should return `$bSalary - $aSalary`. It's supposed to return `-1`, `0`, or `1`, not `true/false`.

Comment: @Barmar you are absolutely right, I got a bit lazy there.

Answer (score 0):

play with this :

```
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveArrayIterator(your_json($file, TRUE)),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
    );

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
     //your control
}
```

Comment: I am bigner. If you will give an live example for above that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

1st json to php array -> $json_arr = json_decode($json, true);

after that -> you can use **array_multisort** http://php.net//manual/en/function.array-multisort.php